# An error occurred while installing "gem" and Bundler cannot continue. Mac OS - big sur

Tags: ruby, rubygems, v8, macos-big-sur, therubyracer

This error happened to me before with nio4r gem when I upgraded to Catalina and @dmitry barskov answered it. A similar issue is happening now after big sur upgrade with json, oj and therubyracer (tried using the solution from nio4r, but no luck). When I run `gem list` I see the gems installed but bundle install fails. So I tried bundle update json oj therubyracer. it works for json and oj but for therubyracer, it throws errors.

therubyracer error -->

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/me/.gem/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/ext/v8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210106-9670-edtaxk.rb extconf.rb --with-v8-dir\=/usr/local/opt/v8
checking for -lpthread... yes
checking for -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --with-objclib
    --without-objclib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
    --with-v8-dir
    --with-v8-include
    --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
    --with-v8-lib
    --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/me/.gem/gems/libv8-3.16.14.19/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': By using --with-system-v8, you have chosen to use the version
(Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
of V8 found on your system and *not* the one that is bundled with
the libv8 rubygem.

However, your system version of v8 could not be located.

Please make sure your system version of v8 that is compatible
with 3.16.14.19 installed.
```

json error -->

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20210106-29155-126itgi.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/me/.gem/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/me/.gem/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c:861:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
bundler (1.17.3)
json (1.8.3)
libv8 (3.16.14.17)
oj (2.15.0)
rake (10.4.2)
ref (2.0.0)
therubyracer (0.12.3)
```

`checking for v8.h... no` I understand that this maybe an issue, so here's what I've tried to fix it, unsuccessfully ->

```
brew install v8-315
gem uninstall -a libv8
bundle config build.therubyracer --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.17' — —with-system-v8
gem uninstall -a therubyracer
bundle config build.libv8 --with-system-v8
gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.2' -- --with-v8-dir=$(brew --prefix v8@3.15)
```

When I do bundle update, it gets stuck in resolving dependencies.... I kept it running for 12 hours before I gave up.
When I delete my gemfile.lock, and run bundle install, it gets stuck in resolving dependencies... again.

I'm using ruby v 2.3.1
bundler version 1.17.3

One thing I noticed was the path `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby` shows 2.6.0 but I'm using 2.3.1 (confirmed by running rbenv local and ruby -v)

If any other information is needed, please tell me. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The first thing to investigate is definitely going to be the issue you mention at the end - your local shell is using your `rbenv` installed Ruby version but from the logs it's very clear that your system Ruby is being used. This log line in particular: `--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)`. I would start by uninstalling Ruby from rbenv, reinstalling it, and then making sure that your `bundle` executable points to your rbenv-installed one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the project folder and clone a new one. Removed all gems, reinstalled rbenv like @taylorthurlow pointed out.

Things worked, bundle install was green.